# CSP, connect-src and excel in base64

Tags: angular, base64, web-config, content-security-policy

In Angular I create an excel file for download:

```
urltoFile(url: string) {
        return fetch(url)
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.arrayBuffer();
            })
            .then(function(buf) {
                return new File([buf], 'excelfile.xlsx', {
                    type: 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                });
            });
    }
```

but in CSP headers in my web.config I have `connect-src *;` and get this error on the server:

Refused to connect to 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,(base64code)' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src *". Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'data:' must be added explicitly.

Question: how this 'connect-src' rule should look to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all: * matches http, https, ws, wss, but not data:. To allow this, your directive should be "connect-src * data:;". This allows for pretty much anything, and you should try to restrict it by not allowing the wildcard.